# how to disable part ToolStripSplitButton

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to disable the button part of a ToolStripSplitButton in a c# winforms app. As far as I see it is not possible and I would like to avoid a complex solution (rewriting entire toolstripsplitbutton) so I'm trying to disable visually at least, ie. draw a grayed icon when button part disabled.

First I browsed referencesource and found that ToolStripRenderer and ToolStripProfessionalRenderer uses some 'internal' properties and methods in OnRenderItemImage(ToolStripItemImageRenderEventArgs e) so I cannot mimic (copy-and-modify-a-bit) the behaviour of OnRenderItemImage.

Next I tried the following code.
Basically it works, the toolStripSplitButton1 is grayed out when the Tag is boolean false.
But this solution kills all my System.Windows.Forms.Timer somehow! Try this code, when toolStripSplitButton1.Tag == false then the toolstrip-independent timer1 does not tick anymore. And the toolStripSplitButton1 tooltip does not show up (guess because it uses Timer as well).
(button1 and button1_Click is just for toggle toolStripSplitButton1.Tag)

My first question is why OnRenderItemImage kills all System.Windows.Forms.Timer?

Second question is how to achieve the original aim to gray out button icon at least visually independently of the button itself?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            toolStrip1.Renderer = new MyToolStripProfessionalRenderer();

            toolStripSplitButton1.Tag = false; // this is for disabling button part
            toolStripSplitButton1.ToolTipText = "toolStripSplitButton1 ToolTip";

            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Tick += T_Tick;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        int ticks = 0;
        private void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ticks++);
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripSplitButton1.Tag = !((bool)toolStripSplitButton1.Tag);
        }
    }

    class MyToolStripProfessionalRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnRenderItemImage(ToolStripItemImageRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Item.Enabled &&
                    e.Item.Tag?.GetType() == typeof(bool) &&
                    !(bool)e.Item.Tag)
                {
                    e.Item.Enabled = false;
                    base.OnRenderItemImage(e);
                    e.Item.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                    base.OnRenderItemImage(e);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // this never reached, there's no exceptions
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Designer.cs:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            this.toolStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
            this.toolStripSplitButton1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSplitButton();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.toolStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // toolStrip1
            // 
            this.toolStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.toolStripSplitButton1});
            this.toolStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.toolStrip1.Name = "toolStrip1";
            this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(352, 25);
            this.toolStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.toolStrip1.Text = "toolStrip1";
            // 
            // toolStripSplitButton1
            // 
            this.toolStripSplitButton1.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            this.toolStripSplitButton1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("toolStripSplitButton1.Image")));
            this.toolStripSplitButton1.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            this.toolStripSplitButton1.Name = "toolStripSplitButton1";
            this.toolStripSplitButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 22);
            this.toolStripSplitButton1.Text = "toolStripSplitButton1";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 64);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(352, 265);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.toolStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.toolStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip toolStrip1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSplitButton toolStripSplitButton1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your goal? What's the usage of a `SplitButton` which it's button part is disabled but user can select an item from it's dropdown?

Comment: It's a combined save button. Pressing the button part does 'normal' save. It should be disabled when there's no changes in the data. Dropdown part contains 'Save as' and 'Save modifications only' (this makes sense in the context of my app) and they should always be accessible. (I know that the buildup of my menu structure can be organized differently to avoid the need of partly disabling the button, but I'm looking for a way for doing this.) In general, I can't understand why .net uses 'internal' stuff in an overridable method...

Comment: You have to be careful what you do in a paint event.  Doing anything that causes the paint event to be triggered again gets your UI thread to burn 100% core.  Seems to work just fine, other than the roar of the cooling fan drowning out the ability to think, but yes, timers stop ticking.  You cannot mess with the Enabled property like that, changing it triggers the paint event again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using a timer for tracking the change is a good idea. What I suggest is create a changeOccurred event and do the operations inside the event.